# Menu icons in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, cms, drupal-6

How do I get menu icons in drupal? I have the menu icons module....but are there menu icon themes or packs or something?

I am using the deco theme, and want menu icons like thus: [image]

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/project/menu_icons
u